# Is raw-printing HTTP_REFERER in HTML exploitable for XSS?

Tags: html, security, http, xss, url-encoding

I'm thinking about raw-printing a bunch of environmental HTTP variables from the environment, directly into HTML.

It would seem like all variables should be safe to go direct into HTML, since they're controlled either by the client directly, or by their proxy server.

Except for `$http_referer`.

Is there a chance that `HTTP_REFERER` can be used for Cross-Site-Scripting attacks?  It would appear that it's always supposed to be URL-encoded in proper browsers; is that the case at all?

Comment: Don't rely on _anything_ that you're not directly in control of. `HTTP_REFERER` can be easily spoofed, or wrong, or absent. Don't rely on it at all.

Comment: _“I'm thinking about raw-printing a bunch of environmental HTTP variables from the environment, directly into HTML”_ – since that’s where you are going wrong already, this is also the only thing you need to fix. So simply apply whatever method your environment provides for proper escaping of such output, and this whole question become null and void.

Comment: @CBroe, I'm generating content with nginx (e.g. similar to [mdoc.su](http://mdoc.su/)), and nginx doesn't seem to support escaping.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I don't care one bit if it's spoofed.  I only care that an attacker has no way of supplying `<` and `>` through a real browser, and only if such browser is to interpret my page as `text/html`.

Comment: _“I'm generating content with nginx”_ – no idea what exactly that means, but can’t you pipe it through something else first?

Comment: @CBroe, pipe it?  Like, with a bash pipe? ;)

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are implementing similar functionality to the [`TRACE`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/trace.html) HTTP method although in HTML.

Check out [Cross Site Tracing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing) for some of the vulnerabilities that you should be aware of (such as displaying HTTP only cookies in the page that could then be read by JavaScript should any XSS vulnerabilities also exist).

To answer your question - If you are outputting to HTML, why not HTML encode anyway?

If your question is more of a theoretical discussion rather than a practical decision that you are making, then yes the URL presented in the referer header should be properly percent encoded.

This means that an attacker redirecting their victim through the page `http://example.com/<script>alert('foo')</script>` should produce the following header.

```
Referer: http://example.com/%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27foo%27%29%3C/script%3E
```

which *should* not trigger an XSS attack. However, all browsers are implemented differently and I would not rely on them all following standards correctly. For example, this is the referer shown in [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) after a redirect from the URL `http://127.0.0.1/%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27foo%27)` (filename `<script>alert('foo')`). The browser percent encoded the request for the URL `http://127.0.0.1/<script>alert('foo')` before the original request, so the referer will use the already converted URL.

[image: Referer]

Comment: Do you mind providing some references?  I've looked at both the RFC for URL encoding (rfc3986?), as well as the HTTP spec itself (rfc7231?), but couldn't find any mention that URLs within the Referer field must always be URL-encoded.  In fact, from RFC3986, I somehow got the impression that URLs need not necessarily be URL encoded at all times (which, in actuality, is already the case when they are shown within the address bar of many modern browsers, even though on copy-paste the string is, in fact, URL-encoded, e.g. take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mg_%28editor%29).

Comment: Yes, RFC 3986. `path` consists of `segment` which consists of `pchar` which is `unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`.

Comment: @cnst: Just wondered if there was any reason why you don't HTML encode since you're outputting it to HTML anway?

Comment: as I've already mentioned, I'm using nginx.conf to write the site (e.g. similar to how [mdoc.su](http://mdoc.su/) is written)